# Jediatable with grails - how to get other params while changing a field data in controller?

Tags: jquery, grails, parameters, gsp, jeditable

[image]
Using Jeditable plugin for my GSP page as below.I want to send the jobid as param while saving the changes done to field so that i can save the correct record in table.

fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/358ES/3/

Controller code for **update function** for saving is -

```
def update = {
    println params
     //saving will come here.
}
```

Params printing as below on console -

```
  [id:select_2, value:daily, action:update, controller:auth]  //I NEED JOB ID AS PARAM.
```

How can i get which row id  is clicked for change?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a work around to this problem and added the jobId to each column name so when its submit will get the ID.